# What does every root is at the same level mean

Tags: graphs, binary-trees

My textbook says a "complete binary tree" is a "full binary tree" where every root is at the same level.

My conceptual understanding:

All this time, I was led by my textbook to believe a root is the "top-most vertex" in which all the other vertex are led away from it. So basically I am led to believe there can be only one root in a tree.

Questions:

What does "where every root is at the same level" even mean?

Isn't a root suppose to be at level 0 all the time?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say every leaf is at the same level?

Comment: Nope. The textbook says "The graph representing such a network is a complete binary tree, that is, a full binary tree where every root is at the same level." page 751"Discrete Mathematics and its Application 7th edition written by Kenneth Rosen. I think your statement is referring to "balanced rooted trees" if my memory serves me right.

Comment: It is a typo then.  A full binary tree means that every internal node has either 0 or 2 children.  A complete one is then a full tree with all the leaves the same distance from the root.

Comment: Isn't a full binary tree the same thing as a "2-ary tree"? I thought the internal node must have exactly 2 children for full binary tree. My textbook never spoke about internal nodes having 0 children for full binary tree.

Comment: No, "binary" and "2-ary" have identical meaning: a 2-ary tree is the same thing as a binary tree (not necessarily full).

Comment: @Louis An internal node cannot, by definition, have zero children: a node with no children is a leaf.

Comment: Another point in favor of a typo is "every root". How many roots is a full binary tree supposed to have? If the answer is 1, then the condition is trivially satisfied for any full binary tree. A member of a singleto set shares all its properties with all other members of the same set. :)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I won't argue and say that its vacuously true. :)  A full tree means every node has zero or 2 children.

Comment: @Louis Touché :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically is a typo, every leaf at same level may be the correct words